# Laravel Form POST redirect failure

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm having a very frustrating (super-newbie) experience with Laravel 5.1. 
Sure there must be something that I'm missing, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything on Laravel docs.

The problem is this (and I believe is even relatively simple): while all GET routes are working, the routes in POST are 'rerouting' me to the wrong place. 
For instance, assuming that the controller is this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use View;

class PagesController extends BaseController {


  public function hello(){
    return view('hello');

  }




 public function register(){
    //Registration rules
    $inputData=array(
            'name' => \Input::get('name'),
             'email' =>\Input::get('email'),
             'password' => bcrypt(\Input::get('password')),
        );  


        createUser($inputData);

    return view('stat');
  }     




 private function createUser($inputData){
    return User::create($inputData);
  }

}
```

and given the route:

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@hello');
```

this one redirects me correctly to the view specified in the controller,at the method indicated.

A POST operation cannot be successfully performed, since

```
Route::post('/','PagesController@register');
```

with the form having:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
        <label for="name">User Name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
        <label for="name">E-mail</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
        <label for="password">password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="auth!"/>
    </form>
```

results in redirecting me to xampp home page.
For example, the "main registration page" is at this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/laravel/project1/public/
```

(GET OK)
and when I click on the submit button, I'm sent to

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Just few more indicators for you to try and help me (I'm genuinely stuck):
1) I didn't use a VirtualHost (searched on the web, but had always no luck in configuring apache properly...good luck I've got xampp)
2) The page "hello" has a link that I used as a test:

```
<a href="stat">Link</a>
```

and it redirects me correctly to the sought-after

```
http://localhost:8080/laravel/project1/public/stat
```

3)In the POST method, I've used a `dd($inputData)` to see what was going wrong, and as a result I had...nothing. Not a blank page,just always the `localhost` page. This led me to think that somehow the controller method isn't called, since no `dd(---)` result got in page.
Hope someone can help.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is http://localhost:8080 , so when you set action to '/' , it goes to root. It`s not good practice , but your solution is to change :

```
<form action="/laravel/project1/public/" method="post">
```

I`d create a virtual host for the project in apache , so document root would be /laravel/project1/public/ .

Comment: hi bignick, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I tried that solution as well, but I get no redirection towards /stat, instead I get the page "laravel/project1/public/" to be reloaded (even if the method in the controller has other actions). I'll try to configure a vhost in Apache and see if something changes

Answer (score 0):

you are posting your form to the root `/` that is why you are being routed to xampp page. To solve this problem, change your form action to this

```
<form action="/post/my/form" method="post">
```

in your routes

```
Route::post('/post/my/form','PagesController@register');
```

Comment: you just need to set the document root in xampp to the public folder of your laravel project as this is what is served to the web the rest of the app is private and then your code will work as you have it.